# Tomcat6 manager installation error

Tags: sudo, tomcat6

I am new to linux .I am trying to install Tomcat6 .I installed it successfully but for manager webapp html GUI I have changes my tomcat-users.xml file as

```
/etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml

 <tomcat-users> 
 <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
   <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <user username="root" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui
 "/> 
 </tomcat-users>
```

saved it using sudo nano command (as root login)
when I try to use tomcat manager it shows me login dialog box but login is unsuccessful 
shows me 401 Unauthorized page why there is no authorization to execute this?
I have start stop and restarted my tomcat whenever needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now its working

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<user username="root" password="admin" roles="manager"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
<user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
<user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
```